# Convert JSON response containing byte[] to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, json, image, cocoa-touch, arrays

I am working with an API that is sending me a JSON response containing an NSArray of bytes represented with integers.

See link for example (bottom example).

http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponse

Here is a snippet of that example:

```
{
   "isMessageAvailable":true,
   "fieldInfo":{
      "responseFieldType":"text",
      "imageFieldType":"image",
      "image":[
         66,
         77,
         58,
         116,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         54,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         40,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         -91,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         45,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         32,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         4,
         116,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -9,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -17,
         -17,
         -17,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -13,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -9,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -17,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0
      ],
      "minimumLength":-1,
      "maximumLength":-1,
      "displayString":"Please enter the text shown in the image"
   },
   "timeOutTime":99900,
   "itemId":10014925,
   "retry":false
}
```

NSJSONSerialization will actually convert this to an NSArray of NSNumbers I believe.

I am confused as to how I would convert an NSArray of NSNumbers to image data.

I looked around on google and found examples in PHP, Java and C++, but nothing specifically for Objective-C/Cocoa.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Oh, getting binary image data as JSON. That's sick.

Comment: tell me about it... I am not a fan of this at all.

Comment: It's an array of bytes (though rather inefficiently represented).  First map (ie, copy byte by byte) it from the NSArray of NSNumbers to a `byte[]` array, then feed that into the appropriate image interfaces.  (But you need to know what type of image it is in order to pick the "appropriate" interfaces.)

Comment: I can tell that this is going to be a blast.

Comment: (It would make a lot more sense to transmit the data as a Base64 string.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't involved in the decision to use this API and its sort-of set in stone.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
NSArray *jsonBytes = ...    

char *bytes = malloc(jsonBytes.count);

NSUInteger index = 0;

for (NSNumber *byteNumber in jsonBytes) {
    bytes[index++] = [byteNumber charValue];
}

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes
                                    length:jsonBytes.count
                              freeWhenDone:YES];

//maybe also specify the scale
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: the UIImage is nil when I use this method, do you know why that would be?

Comment: I have sent a request to their support, but its not in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like it's might be a BMP.

Comment: Does UIImage not handle BMP?

Comment: @Kronusdark It should. There are possibly some BMP formats that it doesn't support. I'd suggest saving the `NSData` as a file (`writeToFile`) and look at the image on your Mac and first make sure the file wasn't corrupted by the API somehow. Then you can dive into details on the file format (share it with us, look at the properties in Photoshop or something like that, etc.).

Comment: @Sulthan Usually the "BM" prefix indicates BMP format, not just raw image data.

Comment: I attempted to write it to disk, but none of the apps I have are able to render the image.

Comment: If I view the memory in Xcode, I get this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngqm9t9m19697fs/Screenshot%202014-06-24%2012.31.02.png

Comment: @Kronusdark We should move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56216/convert-json-response-containing-byte-to-uiimage